# How to create create-react-app vendor bundle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vendor, code-splitting

Using [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app), how do you go about creating a separate vendor bundle?

Code splitting is done pretty easily using the [`react-code-splitting`](https://github.com/didierfranc/react-code-splitting) package, but I've not found anything concrete about creating vendor bundles in a `create-react-app` project.

Comment: You can run `npm run eject` (it is one way operation) that will eject the webpack config. Then you can edit that webpack configuration according to your requirement.

Comment: [Important note on `eject`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject): "Note: this is a one-way operation. Once you eject, you can’t go back!".

Comment: Yes, it's one-way.  I thought about doing so, and might just do that.  But I'm hesitant because I truly do enjoy `create-react-app`'s ease of use.  I'm thinking I can't be the only one with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It might land in react-scripts@2.0 .Here is a [link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3815) where you can find more info. At the moment you have to eject to use the code-splitting